# using API Guard with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am Implement a Key authentication in laravel 5.2  using this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/chrisbjr/api-guard)

it is giving me an error

```
 ErrorException in ApiGuardAuth.php line 14:
Argument 1 passed to Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\ApiGuardAuth::__construct() must be an instance of Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\Contracts\Providers\Auth, null given, called in E:\xammp\htdocs\vox\didww\vendor\chrisbjr\api-guard\src\Providers\ApiGuardServiceProvider.php on line 49 and defined
```

here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\Models;
use Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\Http\Controllers\ApiGuardController;



class BooksController extends ApiGuardController
{

    public function all()
    {
        return "die";
        $books = \App\User::all();

        return $this->response->withCollection($books, new BookTransformer);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        try {

            $book = \App\User::findOrFail($id);

            return $this->response->withItem($book, new BookTransformer);

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {

            return $this->response->errorNotFound();

        }
    }

}
```

i have also updated a app.php and kernal.php 
any suggestions?

P.S sorry for my bad english

Comment: i have also followed this  [link](https://blog.muya.co.ke/api-guard-laravel-5-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error was introduced between 3.0.3 and 3.1.0 try downgrading to 3.0.3 may be this helps.

you can also try to update latest package of Api-gaurd

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this on my build by adding this block to the `app/config/apiguard.php` file.

```
'providers'            => [
    'auth' => Chrisbjr\ApiGuard\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class
],
```